# transparency flickering on composite/render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu, effects

I made a motion tracking animation in blender. i go to render it and the transparency flickers on the two render layers added to the composite.

Blender: 3.1.2, render: gpu, gpu: rtx 3050, OptiX.

[image: frame 1]

[image: frame 3]

[image: node setup(defalt)]

How can i fix this?

Comment: node-tree seems to be OK ... also in your screen doesn't flickering light, but transparency ... if that is happening randomly in frames try to render without GPU, but it doesn't looks like an graphic card issue ... but who knows :)

Comment: okay, have an i5 so its a bit slow.

Comment: @myrccar how did you fix it? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @utiq changed to cuda in blenders gpu setings